# How to loop through an array of objects and filter out the items that are in the same hour

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with what I am sure is a simple loop and filter process.

I want to loop through this array and return only the objects that are in the same hour i.e. 8am - 9am or 10am - 11am **not** 8:30am to 9:30am so that means all the 8ams and 10 ams would be returned in this example.

I have an array of objects like so

```js
let arr = [{
     "action": "Coffee with client", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 08:30:15"},
    {"action": "Check Email", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 08:32:37"},
    {"action": "Order Breakfast Sandwich", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 08:45:43"},
    {"action": "Walk Back To Office", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 09:15:58"},
    {"action": "Attend Morning Meeting", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 10:15:00"}, 
    {"action": "Add Meeting Notes To Calendar", 
     "time": "1/12/2018 10:45:37"}]
```

I'm struggling with how to group these date time strings. I have tried converting them and doing something like this where what I want to do is convert the string to a date (number) and compare each item in the array to see if its in the same hour and if it is return those items. I'm lost right now and any help would be appreciated.

```
const hour = 1000 * 60 * 60;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
   const difference = Date.parse(arr[i+1].time) - 
   Date.parse(arr[i].time)

   if(difference < hour) {
      //return all items in the same hour

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the hour from the date and make an object keyed to hour where each value is an array of items.

```js
let arr = [{"action": "Coffee with client", "time": "1/12/2018 08:30:15"},{"action": "Check Email", "time": "1/12/2018 08:32:37"},{"action": "Order Breakfast Sandwich", "time": "1/12/2018 08:45:43"},{"action": "Walk Back To Office", "time": "1/12/2018 09:15:58"},{"action": "Attend Morning Meeting", "time": "1/12/2018 10:15:00"}, {"action": "Add Meeting Notes To Calendar", "time": "1/12/2018 10:45:37"}]

let grouped = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
  let hour = new Date(item.time).getHours()  // the key for the object
  if (!obj[hour]) obj[hour] = []             // new array if it doesn't exist
  obj[hour].push(item)                       // add item to correct group
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(grouped)
```

All the 8 appoints will be grouped with `grouped[8]`, etc.

It's not clear if you will have appointments from more that one date and what should happen with those.

Comment: This is awesome thanks! Would you mind explaining a little more deeply whats happening? Specifically with getHours and why you are checking for the array if it exists first?

Comment: @gwar9 the first time you see a particular hour — say 8— when you're looping through the array, value `obj['8']` will be undefined. So we define it as an empty array `[]`. Once it's defined we can push into the array. The next time we see an `8` hour, we don't want to make a new array because it already exists—you can just push into the existing array. That's why we test first.